# NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.CheckBox.setOnClickListener on a null object reference, ONLY on tablets

Tags: java, android

I saw many similar questions online, and tried several solutions. But none fixed my issue. One important thing I want to mention is that, my code works well on android Phones, it only crashes on android Tablets. I have no idea what's going on.

This is the stack:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxxx.xxxx.android/com.xxxx.xxxx.android.LoginScreenActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.CheckBox.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2873)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1482)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6145)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.CheckBox.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
at com.xxxx.xxxx.android.LoginScreenActivity.onCreate(LoginScreenActivity.java:89)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6374)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2752)
... 10 more
```

This is the LoginScreenActivity:

```
public class LoginScreenActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    private Context context;
    private CheckBox showPassword;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_screen);

        context = getApplicationContext();
        showPassword = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox_show_password);

        //below is line 89 of LoginScreenActivity, exception happened here.
        showPassword.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view)
          {
            //.................
          }
        });
    }
}
```

Here's the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox_show_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Show Password"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: its not duplicate because of this

Comment: Do you happen to have another layout in a `res/layout-land` folder that doesn't have that ID? That would be a reason that it is null.

Comment: most likely its the interface i guess.

Comment: I think @cricket_007 is on the right track. If you have a any other layout folders in res/ (such as "layout-sw600dp") it would absolutely explain why only tablets aren't working.

Comment: @helldawg13 Explain? How would `implements OnClickListener` cause the null pointer?

Comment: I think that's the reason.... I do have more than one layout there.... actually I have all of them. `layout-land`, `layout-xlarge`, `layout-xlarge-land`. Does it mean that I have to copy this checkbox to all the layouts?

Comment: @cricket_007 i guess just because otherwise he would have to do showPassword.setOnClickListener(this) and do the implementation in the abstract method onClick

Comment: @helldawg13 That wouldn't cause a null pointer, though. Also, `this` wasn't used at all, and there is nothing wrong with an anonymous class. I'm convinced the problem is another layout resource that doesn't have that ID.

Comment: @YabinSong what have you tried so far?

Comment: Actually what is the point of instanciating a variable since she(cause she is a girl i suppose) could use LoginScreenActivity.this

Comment: @helldawg13 yes exactly, she could be using it with a get/set to pass into an `Asyc` or something.

Comment: Unluckly the testing tablet is dead, there's some issue on it, it takes forever to charge. So I'm waiting for it now. But I'm going to add the checkbox to other layouts, and I will try landscape view first. Hopefully it will work.

Comment: Maybe we are all wrong and you should modify the implements View.OnClickListener and also showPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener) because you actually trying to set a listener to a View

Comment: @YabinSong Yes also try removing the parent layouts to see if that is causing an issue (one time  a `scrollview` was not initialized properly and it could not find my `button` child)

Comment: @YabinSong I am pretty sure that `login_screen` is not the xml that you posted above.

Comment: Okay, I added the checkbox to layout-land, it fixed my issue on the phone that when I rotates the screen to landscape, the app crashes. I was working on both issues. Obviously both issue caused by same reason. I only have my checkbox in the layout folder. I should add it to all the layout folders xml files.

Comment: @YabinSong If you want the app to look exactly the same on every device, you should probably delete the other layout folders. That way you only have a single layout to worry about.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two problems that are apparent.

The obvious: `NullPointerException`

The solution: All instances of `login_screen.xml` will need a `Checkbox` with `android:id="@+id/checkbox_show_password"` in order for `findViewById(R.id.checkbox_show_password)` to not return null.

This is worth mentioning because in the comments it was stated that there are multiple `res/layout-*` folders and the error only happens on tablets, so that is important.

Second problem:

While any `View` can use an `OnClickListener`, you have a `CheckBox`, not a `Button`, so you'll probably want to know when the checkbox was checked, not just clicked.

In that case, use an `OnCheckedChangeListener`

```
showPassword.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked){
            // do something
        }else {
            //do something else
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The first problem is the one caused the issue. Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: what is the difference from my answer?

Comment: @helldawg13 I actually addressed the error in the question. As I stated in the comments, changing the listener doesn't fix the null value.

Comment: thats why you copied mine..:D

Comment: @helldawg13 I didn't copy. You have `showPassword.isChecked()` and I don't. I don't control Android class names or the variable names used in the question. The code is the "same" because that is how it needs to be implemented.

Answer (score 3):

Well with a checkbox you cannot have an `onClickListener`. Please remove the Interface (`implements`) also. You may want to try this:

```
showPassword.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (showPassword.isChecked()){
                    //do something
                }else {
                    //do something else
                }
            }
        });
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: But the onClickListener works fine on phones, any idea why?

Comment: Actually, any `View` can have an `OnClickListener`. It is just that `OnCheckedChangeListener` is more appropriate

Comment: Is this the reason cause the crash?

Comment: with the compound buttons its better to have setOnCheckedChangeListener.....@YabinSong try it and tell us

Comment: If a variable is null, using a different listener doesn't fix anything.

Comment: how can it be null when he initializes it before setting the listener

Comment: The nested layouts can cause this, try isolating then add one layout back at a time

Comment: omg...remove the implements OnClickListener interface....

Comment: I upvoted your answer since it's useful. But it's not why the app crashes. That's why I accepted his answer. :)